# Making SQL Query with RODBC With Table That Has A Backslash In Its Name

Tags: sql, r, string, character, rodbc

I'm looking to make an SQL query using RODBC to pull some data off a server I have access to. However, an issue I am running into is that the table name has a single backslash in its name.

My statement looks something like this for an example.

```
qry <- "SELECT * FROM [User\MyTable]"
```

However, R does not allow a single backslash like that my knowledge. Now, I'm aware to denote a single backslash I have to escape that backslash, so I tried doing something like this:

```
qry <- "SELECT * FROM [User\\MyTable]"
```

However, when I run the RODBC function to get the table, it fails:

```
 df <- sqlQuery(myConnection, qry)
```

Saying I cannot find the table and if you print out `df`, it shows the query, which has two back slashes in it! Not sure where to go from here and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: I didn't solved my problem, but worked around it. It turns out the part with the slash was the schema of the table and not the table name itself. A more specific `"database="` portion of the `odbcConnect` function helped solve the problem.

Comment: Wow. *Why* would someone name a table like this?

Comment: I believe it's an automatic system that links the creator of the table/view to the author, which is of the form "User/Table". Unfortunate, I know.

Comment: You need to specify your RDMS. Each have special escape characters like square brackets (MS Access, SQLite, SQL Server), backticks (MySQL), double quotes (Postgres, Oracle, DB2 -and ANSI standard).

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. Same issue with the square brackets or not.